# When collecting Legendary gear from a dweller returning from the wasteland, is the icon also blue like a Rare item?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Based on the question "[Is it possible to find power armor in the wasteland?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/227214/is-it-possible-to-find-power-armor-in-the-wasteland)", it looks like I may have accidentally sold a set of Expert Radiation Suit (P3, E4) when collecting gear.

My question is, if your dweller returns with Legendary gear and you sell off junk, is your Legendary gear blue just like Rare gear?

I didn't particularly notice the sell price, but I wasn't expecting it so I didn't even check.

UPDATE:  I figured out where it went.  The dweller went out with regular radiation suit, and wore the new found suit, so I was not able to locate it when collecting gear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer specifically for the current build, but in previous versions legendary gear was shown in a blue box.  This could be confirmed by checking videos of people using the negative time glitch to get legendary items, such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nP4JW1boP4).